# C# Gridview- Focus and change specific value for database

Tags: c#, sql

I have built a gridview in a C# form that allows me to edit in a database in a single form. However, I want it to operate in a different way:

- When I double click a row, it opens ONLY the specific row, with the corresponding columns in a single form.
- As soon as it opens, I edit the row. It saves in the database.

What I want to try to do is:

```
SELECT ColumnName1, ColumnName2 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ColumnName1 = @ParameterName
```

Where the parameter name is the ID in which i double click i another form. I am putting my work so far:

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;




namespace TestInventory
{


  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'prismaWinPosDataSet.Inventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.prismaWinPosDataSet.Inventory);
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            //      inventoryBindingSource.Update(prismaWinPosDataSet,"Inventory");
            gridView1.PostEditor(); //save the cell value to a data source 
            gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow(); //update the row and raise the RowUpdated event 
                                          //   dbContext

        inventoryTableAdapter.Update(this.prismaWinPosDataSet.Inventory);

    }
```

// Cell validation rules

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
   //     context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    private void simpleButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inventoryBindingSource.AddNew();
    }


    private void simpleButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (XtraMessageBox.Show("Delete?", "Message",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)==DialogResult.Yes);
        inventoryBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }

    private void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   int invID = gridView1.GetRow;

        Form2 frm = new Form2(2);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
}
```

Single form is working normally, updating in the database.[image: single Form]
Message box "ok" is because I haven't accomplished to connect it to the query in the second form.

Comment: When you say "*it opens ONLY the specific row*", what do you mean by "opens"?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Get only current row. Windows Form.